# Position CSS rotated text to left of image?

Tags: css

Here is my site:
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/4/test

Im rotating text with CSS. I want the text to sit to the left of the image:

[image]

Note ive only added the webkit prefix for the css at the moment. So this is my rough div structure and CSS.

```
<div>
 <img src="whatever.jpg" />
 <p>Here is some text</p>
</div>

p {
                margin: 0;
                text-align: center;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            }
```

Comment: You should probably add `transform: rotate(-90deg);` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 *{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;       
}
figure{
    position:relative;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:4px solid #ccc;
}

img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
figcaption {
 text-align: center;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
transform: rotate(-90deg); 
position: absolute;
left: -100px;
top: 60px;
width: 150px;
height: 20px;
 }
```

the markup

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://www.disney.co.uk/brave/common/images/characters/merida.png" />
    <figcaption>Here is some text</figcaption>
</figure>
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/NeeXm/

Comment: You should probably add `transform: rotate(-90deg);` as well.

Comment: sure -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);  too

Comment: For the figcaption I would use Position: relative; instead of absolute.

Comment: @David Yancey position absolute is correct since the parent figure hast a relative position check w3c for more infos please

Comment: @kougiland Thank you, for some reason I was thinking absolute position was relative to the window and not the first positioned ancestor.  You learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `position` to `absolute`. After that play with `left` and `top` values to bring it to left middle position.

Comment: Why not `float: left;`?

Comment: That's another possibility.

Comment: @tcak absolution positing was my first thought but I cant get it to work.

Comment: @BryceHanscomb if I float it left it does go to the left of the image, but it sits at the bottom, its not centered 1/2 way up the image.